# Keyboard problem in Fedora 15

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, fedora, keyboard-layout

I've just installed new Fedora 15 Beta and I'm facing a problem which I haven't faced in Alpha version.
I'm not sure if I would be able to describe the problem, so I will use screenshots.

This is an example menu bar taken from Firefox: 
[image: Firefox menu bar]

As you can see, I can use `<Alt>` + `<Z>` to get to Zakladki menu (it's Bookmarks in English). However, in Poland we use `<Alt>` + `<Z>` to get special polish letter `ż` (same goes with `<Alt>` + {`<E>`, `<N>`, `<c>`}). The problem is: Fedora seems to take right `<Alt>` key as a shortcut key, so when I use `<Alt>` + `<Z>`, Bookmarks menu opens up. Of course I do not want it to open, I want to use my Right Alt for polish letters.

I use IBus input system, polish keyboard layout and I didn't experience any problems like this on Fedora 15 Alpha.
I have no idea if does this matter, but I use wireless keyboard - Microsoft Bluetoth Keyboard 6000.

Comment: Sounds like you should report it as a bug. Against ibus component I guess? Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the keyboard layout options and make Right Alt the key to choose the 3rd level.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However, do you think I should report this as a bug (shouldn't it be default if I chosen polish layout during installation)?

Comment: I would report this as a feature request, that certain options should be set by default for specific keyboard layouts.